# Mysql - Insert null where no value exists

Tags: mysql

To keep things super simple and not be long winded explaining the full situation. If I have a query where if both values are true, i get a response but if only one value is true, I get zero rows returned which is understandable but is there a way to get a null in the field where the vale is not true? like the below query.

```
select user_id, office_id
from user_table
where user_id = 23 and office_id = 40; -- here both values are true
```

So in this example the employee has a user_id of 23 AND they are a member of the office #40 so the below result would show

```
user_id | office_id 
23&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 40&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

However if user_id 23 was actually a member of office #60, naturally i would get zero rows returned.

```
select first_name, last_name, office_id
from user_table
where user_id = 23 and office_id = 60; 

user_id | office_id 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

What i am hoping is the one true value would show and a null where the 2nd value is false

```
user_id | office_id 
23&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; null&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Any way to edit the below query to get the above result with the null showing for office_id? Hope I made it clear and easy.  Thanks for any help/advice anyone may have

```
select first_name, last_name, office_id
from user_table
where user_id = 23 and office_id = 60;
```

Comment: are you also wanting user_id to be null if it does not match but office_id does?

Comment: Thanks for the reply !  In our case, user_id is a primary key so that will always be there.  Only question is whether the referenced office_id in the query is legit.  So we have logs and from those logs we grab 2 values, user_id and office_id.  Those values are grabbed from separate locations in the logs and placed into an SQL query.  Because the 2 values are not grepped from the same location they will not always be a legitimate pair.   But we need to have a row returned even when the pair does not match.  So have user_id show and a null for office_id.   Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include records with different office_id, simply don't include it in the WHERE clause.  If you want to show null if office_id is not 60, just use an expression in the SELECT columns that gives either office_id 60 or NULL.

```
select first_name, last_name,
    case office_id when 60 then 60 end as office_id
from user_table
where user_id = 23;
```